# Labeling shapefile address numbers in AutoCAD?

Tags: shapefile, labeling, autocad

I am trying to figure out how to label 'ADDR' field in autocad only showing the address number and not the street.

I try using LTRIM and RTRIM expressions and nothing changes the way it shows

How it shows : 123 main st

how i want it: 123

Comment: What autocad version?